# Will I still able to install dependency package via Pip after Python 2 End of Life in 2020?

Tags: python-2.7, pip, pypi

I'm using Python 2.7 and python pip to download all dependency packages from `requirements.txt` file for running my project. As we know the end of life of Python 2 in 2020, I have concern I could not install my dependency package from pip as `pip install -r requirements.txt` anymore.

One way I could think of is download all dependencies from requirements.txt and install them locally. Is it possible?

I have read a similar question [Will PIP work for python 2.7 after its End of Life on 1st Jan 2020](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54915381/will-pip-work-for-python-2-7-after-its-end-of-life-on-1st-jan-2020), but the possibility is still not clear for me whether or not pip still be working or not after 2020 EOL of Python 2.

How could I confirm that? How could I do to keep dependencies still be installed via pip in 2020 end of life of python 2? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will PIP work for python 2.7 after its End of Life on 1st Jan 2020](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54915381/will-pip-work-for-python-2-7-after-its-end-of-life-on-1st-jan-2020)

Comment: @phd , I concerned that dependencies that I used to installed via python pip, pip install -r requirements.txt, such an installed, will no longer be able to install in 2020. If so, how can I ensure I still be able to install those dependencies even in 2020 as normal as before ? I’m really appreciate could you confirm on that, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in the question you linked, the *pip* maintainers are willing to support Python 2.7 for as long as reasonably feasible. Now you need to consider the other side: the index.

The default index for *pip* is [*PyPI*](https://pypi.org), and I can't imagine that they would decide to delete existing artifacts or stop serving them just because the corresponding interpreter reached their *end of life*. I am pretty sure they already host and serve artifacts that are aimed at Python interpreters that have already reached their end of life. See for example the [artifacts for `lxml` version 3.4.4](https://pypi.org/project/lxml/3.4.4/#files) clearly show that it is still serving files aimed at Python 2.6 and 3.4, both of them have alredy reached *EOL*.

> One way I could think of is download all dependencies from requirements.txt and install them locally. Is it possible?

This is definitely feasible as well. You could even go a step further and  host your own index. See the following links for ideas:

- https://packaging.python.org/guides/index-mirrors-and-caches/
- https://packaging.python.org/guides/hosting-your-own-index/
- https://pypi.org/project/devpi/
- https://pypi.org/project/pypiserver/

Comment: you shed the light on me :) . One step further about hosting my own index, I'm worrying, some dependency package might link to another dependency for it to work meaning that while installing one dependency, it will have to download another dependency for it to work. For this case, if default index for pip, PyPI, is changed, then installing locally would failed too as it fails to download dependency that a package need for it to work. Would it be such a case, how can I solve that as I could not know which dependency that package needs for it to work properly? Thanks so much.

Comment: Haven't done any of this myself, but I assume that if you use _devpi_ (or _bandersnatch_) as a cache proxy to _PyPI_ then all downloaded distributions are saved locally: those you explicitly require as well as their dependencies. You could make regular backups of your local _pip cache_. You could have a look at the output of `pip freeze` to get a feeling of what projects you have already installed. And again, most likely you don't need to do any of this, not for the foreseeable future at least.