# Creating a local python pip repo

Tags: python, python-2.7, repository, pypi, bandersnatch

**I am tasked to create and use a local PIP repo.**

*(the reason being that we'll be using Python 2.7 for at least one more year and fear of packages or older versions being removed)*

I am looking at `bandersnatch` and it is not clear to me whether it is an on-line mirroring tool which i need to run as a service, or can be used to offload a one-off copy?

I'd prefer a second option (don't want to complicate the system unnecessarily), and would be satisfied by running an update say daily or even weekly.

An alternative approach would be to download only the packages and version we actually use by looking at the requirements.txt file, but this would require running an update every time a developer wants to add or update a package.

Comment: https://packaging.python.org/guides/index-mirrors-and-caches/ -- https://packaging.python.org/guides/hosting-your-own-index/

Comment: I down voted. Question is a bit vague, I am pretty sure I have seen similar questions here already. You would be more likely to get straight answers, if you managed to narrow it down to concrete issues. Asking multiple related questions is probably better as well. It would also avoid opinionated answers.

Comment: @sinoroc I appreciate your input, however I did googled *and* searched on SE and didn't found anything specific.

Comment: I agree, sometimes nothing turns up. I suddenly remembered this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58709224/11138259

Answer (score 1):

A way to create a local python package repository is throught Sonatype Nexus, with Nexus you can create some kinds of repos:

- Hosted repo (our own and internal repo)
- Proxy repo (proxy others repo)
- Group repo (group and priority sort a list of hosted and proxied repos)

For example, you can create a group repo with the following logic order:
- First search the package in my own repo
- If it not exists, search it on global public repo.

It is a transparent way to your app.

https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/formats/pypi-repositories

There is a Docker image if you want too. https://hub.docker.com/r/sonatype/nexus3

I used it before to different purposes and I see it very mature and complete.

Answer (score 0):

a script that generates a simple repository with N recent versions of 4000 most used packages on pypi. Advantage is it can hold multiple versions as in pypi. https://gist.github.com/harisankar-krishna-swamy/cac5d1e6c1ae074b39286c1336bff63d