# Change python used for Anaconda / Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Sorry, if this is a stupid problem but I'm new and don't know how to fix this
I used to have Python 2.7 but since it no longer works, I installed python 3 now how do I change that for Anaconda? because I installed it using the former version

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change default Anaconda python environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28436769/how-to-change-default-anaconda-python-environment)

Comment: "*Python 2.7 … no longer works*" That's not true. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/54915827/7976758

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have the latest version of conda by running

```
conda update conda
```

Then run

```
conda install python=3.8
```