# installing pip on python2.7.5 and the old version issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I want to make some change on a code which has been developed with python2.7.5
so I should use Python 2.7.5.
But when I'm installing pip on python2.7.5, face this error.
I have downloaded get-pip.py and ran it through cmd
here is the error:
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWluD.png)
does it mean we can not use Python2 anymore??

Comment: "*does it mean we can not use Python2 anymore?*" No. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54915827/7976758 You need Python 2.7.9 or higher and proper tools, starting with `pip` < 21.

Comment: Hey thanks for your comment, so if I use Python 2.7.9 I will not have a problem installing pip?

Comment: You can install `pip` even for Python 2.7.5 but due to it using old SSL version `pip` couldn't connect to PyPI.org. Python 2.7.9+ use more recent SSL algorithms so you can continue using Python 2.7 until PyPI.org changes the list of outdated SSL algorithms once more. That will be the end of Python 2.7.

Comment: Can you please tell me what should I exactly do to install pip on Python 2.7.5 ? how can I solve the old SSL version problem to connect to PyPi.org ...?

Comment: Upgrade to Python 2.7.18 (the current last bugfix in Python 2.7 line) or at least Python 2.7.9 (if you codebase is incompatible with later Python 2.7; for example I have code at my job that works with Python 2.7.10 but doesn't work with later Python 2.7.11+). Install `get-pip.py` from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/2.7/

Comment: Thanks dear, I tried Python 2.7.18 and now the pip installed, However the warning says "DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021" I also installed some packages such as numpy and scipy but still have problem installing "PyQt4" the error says "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt4 (from versions: none)"

Comment: PyQt4 was removed from PyPI long ago. Get it from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4 or https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/PyQt-4.11.4/

Comment: Now I downloaded PyQt4 from the site you have mentioned and saved it on c:\Python27\Scripts. But when I tried to run it through cmd another error happened saying : "This file does not have an app associated with it for performing this action..." :-( the Qt4 version which I download is "PyQt4-4.11.4-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl" I am using 64bit windows

Comment: You've asked so many questions about `pip` and don;t know how to install .whl files? Install them using `pip`, of course!

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpful comments. Now it is all ok. Hope you all the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using python 2.7.12 or upper and you can run all python codes in python2

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use python 3 but you should convert your python 2 code using 2to3 package.
To do this you can install 2to3 using pip in python 3 .
Open command prompt and use this command :
pip install 2to3
You should install pip in advance.
Good luck!

Comment: It can be a solution, but the code is very large containing GUI classes and using PyQt4 on Python 2 which is not supported in Python 3